# React returning error #185 for IE11 users

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, react-router

When a user loads my react app (irlmap.com) in IE, and then clicks "Start," I see the error below. I have received and fixed this error many times in other situations, but this particular error is contained to IE users, which is an anomaly I have never previously encountered.

```
> Minified React error #185; visit
> http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=185
```

Which in long form is:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

The point in the code with the "Start" button is using react router, and the button itself is a react router Link.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Toolbar} />
```

...

```
const Toolbar = () => (
    <p className='status'>
       <span className='action'>
          <Link id='action-start-new' to={`/map/${this.props.uid}`}>Start &#8594;</Link>
       </span>
    </p>
 )
```

Comment: Can you show us the component that gets render when this [Link](https://irlmap.com/map/2vZnZM2kksP2sy07o8afI3FkrGO2) links opens?

Comment: This happens also with old versions of MS Edge, were you able to resolve it or find what causes it?